# Installing mongodb-community@6.0 from mongodb/brew is not installing in MAC Ventura 13.0

Tags: mongodb, macos

It showing this error while install mongodb0community@5.0 / 6.0

[image]

Comment: read the error message that says what you need to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you update Ventura It will update Command line tool to 14.1.0.
In Xcode 14.1.0 is RC version so this version will not show in app store you have to download from the https://developer.apple.com/download/all/

Make sure your xcode and command line tool have same version otherwise it will show above error.

I upgraded both to 14.1.0
It work's perfectly